# Finding the longest overlapping interval pair

Tags: algorithms, recursion, intervals

Say I have a list of $n$ integral intervals $[a,b]$ where each represents a set $S = \{a, a+1, \ldots, b\}$. An overlap is defined as $|S_1 \cap S_2|$. Example: $[3,6]$ and $[5,9]$ overlap on $[5,6]$ so the length of that is 2. The task is to find two intervals with the longest overlap in $o(n^2)$ using just recursion and not dynamic programming.

Naive approach is obviously brute force, which does not hold with time complexity condition. I was also unsuccessful trying sweep line algo and/or Longest common subsequence algorithm.

I just cannot find a way of dividing it into subproblems. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312714/finding-maximum-overlapping-interval-pair-in-onlogn Maybe one can quote the answer there?

Comment: @xskxzr that one is just wrong. Not correct at all.

Comment: I didn't check that answer carefully. If you find it's wrong, what about leaving a comment?

Comment: Must you use recursion? Sweep line algorithm does not use recursion.

Comment: How big numbers can $a$ and $b$ be?

Comment: @someone12321 No limits on those.

Comment: @AndrejKováč: Your claim that the solution xskxzr linked to is "just wrong" is not only itself wrong, but unhelpful and lazy.  I suggest trying to give a counterexample to its correctness, and letting that guide you to a proof that it is in fact correct.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try divide-and-conquer.  I can only see about two plausible ways to do the "divide" step; try both of them, and one of them should work to yield a useful algorithm.